# How to keep maximum values in a row and delete the rest?

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with a dull work assignment where I am asked to locate the highest value in a row and delete the rest.

The table in question:

[image]

For the shown table I want to find the highest market share for a product and keep only this value. I have tried numerous times with WorksheetFunction.Max, but the function only locates one of the highest values. In the table, row 1 for example we can see that the product has two equal max values. I want to keep them both and remove the others.

Any help appreciated. Thanks for your time! :)

EDIT:

This is what I have managed to do as code:

```
Sub products()    

Dim row As Integer
Dim highest As Double
Dim start As Integer
Dim final As Integer
Dim v As range

start = 4
final = Worksheets("Sheet1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For row = start To final
    Set v= Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(row)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(v) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Row " & row & " has an empty cell.."
    Else
        highest = WorksheetFunction.Max(v)
    End If
    If v < highest Then
        v.Value = ""
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

It gives error on the last if statement. No idea why.

Comment: You need to loop the rows in the used range of the worksheet, then inside this loop the columns of the used range form column 2 onwards, then if the value is <> the Max value you've found set its value to "" I am on a tablet now so difficult to write the code.

Comment: Google usedrange and for next loops and .columns and .rows look at the VBA help.

Comment: I would personally use a do while loop and iterate through each cell of the row.  Give us some code, and you'll get more specific answers

Comment: Code is now given, albeit broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple approach to your problem, find the comments in the code:

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim max As Integer

Set rng = Range("$A$1:" & Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address) '<-- first of your rows
Do While rng(1) <> "" '<-- while you don't find a blank cell on first position
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(rng) '<-- get the max of current row
    For Each cell In rng '<-- loop through the cells of your row
        If cell.Value <> max Then '<-- if the value of the cell is not the max
            cell.Value = "" '<-- set it to empty
        End If
    Next cell
    Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & rng(1).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Address) '<-- go the below line
    rng.Select
Loop
```

Tip: don't try your code (or at least don't save the file after having tried) directly on your "final" dataset cause you won't be able to revert the modifications.

As for the code you added lately, the reason why it's broken is that you declare your variable `v` as a `Range`:

```
Dim v As Range
```

then you define it as an entire row:

```
Set v= Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(row)
```

but then you use it as if it was a single cell, because you compare it with a variable (`highest`) which is declared as Double:

```
If v < highest Then
```

You can't do this simply because you're telling the code if a row (which is an object of the Sheet) is smaller than a Double value, from which you get a `Type mismatch` exception.

Comment: Matteo, thanks for your code, however, the rows have different ranges, making it impossible to specify exact range.

Comment: @FrankLuther ok, I was missing this information. I have modified my sample accordingly.